# TcpListener actively refused connection

Tags: vb.net, connection, tcplistener

I am maintaining an application that uses a TcpListener to listen for incoming communication. The following code opens the connection:

```
Dim listener As TcpListener
_listenFailed = False
Try
    listener = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Me.Host), Me.Port)
    listener.Start()
Catch ex As Exception
    ' an error here means the settings are likely bogus
    _listenFailed = True
    Return
End Try

While Not _stoplistening
{
    ' Accept connection
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when i send a file from a different computer, I get the error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I have checked for firewalls and antivirus, and there were no blocks. I used

```
netstat -a -n
```

to determine that the port is active and listening. Both applications are running from Visual Studios in Administrator mode, not that this should make a difference. I have a break point set at the first line of the accept connection code, but it never gets run.

I stopped the application and examined the TcpListener, and found that there were a couple errors if I dug deep down. At TcpListener.LocalEndpoint.IPEndPoint.IPAddress.Address.ErrorCode there was the error 10045, "OperationNotSupported". Also, at TcpListener.Socket.RemoteEndPoint.ErrorCode there was an error 1057, "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected, and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied. I don't know if either of these errors are relevant.

If anyone has any insights as to what might be causing this problem, or steps that can be taken to trace the root of the issue, I would be grateful.

Comment: What is the value of Me.Host?

Comment: Is Me.Host an IP address, a loopback, or a workstation name?

Comment: I have confirmed that it is the IPv6 address for the computer. Company policy, unfortunately, prohibits me from publishing the actual IP. Sorry.

Comment: Are you running both the client and the server from the same machine?  Are you specifying the exact same IPv6 address and port on both ends?

Comment: The server is a separate machine. i am using RDP to remote into it.

Comment: Why are you mentioning RDP?  I'm confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
listener = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Me.Host), Me.Port)
```

To this:

```
listener = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Me.Port)
```

This will allow you to listen across all network interfaces.

---

Additionally, you can use `IPv6Any` instead of `Any` if you want to target IPv6 instead.  This choice has an impact on the address used by the client side obviously.

Comment: I am not sure why that solved it, but it did. I had the IP addresses matching correctly before. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tim Perform an 'ipconfig` from the command line and you will see all the different network interfaces exposed by your server.  You typically need to listen on all of those.  If you specify a distinct IP address you limit yourself to just that one.